# Spark --num-executors and number of partitions

Tags: apache-spark

Do the number of executors have to be a factor of the partition count. As I am getting data loss when having 2 executors and 25 partitions.

Answer (score 3):

Not at all! The number of partitions is totally independent from the number of executors (though for performance you should at least set your number of partitions as the number of cores per executor times the number of executors so that you can use full parallelism!).

Maybe you can post your code so that we can tell why you have data loss...